# How can I remove the first part of a string?

Tags: javascript

I have an array with the following kind of strings:

```
var Nameslist = [];

Nameslist.push("home.mytest1.James Thomas 14-47");
Nameslist.push("home.mytest1.George Simon 7-2");
Nameslist.push("home.mytest1.Sandy Kylie 3-15");
```

Now I want to remove the first part of each string in the array. The array should look like this after removing `home.mytest1.`:

```
"James Thomas 14-47"
"George Simon 7-2"
"Sandy Kylie 3-15"
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `Nameslist.map(str => str.replace("home.mytest1.", ""))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` and `replace`

```js
var Nameslist = [];

Nameslist.push("home.mytest1.James Thomas 14-47");
Nameslist.push("home.mytest1.George Simon 7-2");
Nameslist.push("home.mytest1.Sandy Kylie 3-15");

console.log(Nameslist.map(t=>t.replace("home.mytest1.", "")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go with a string replace:

```js
const nameList = [
  'home.mytest1.James Thomas 14-47',
  'home.mytest1.George Simon 7-2',
  'home.mytest1.Sandy Kylie 3-15'
];

const alteredNameList = nameList.map(value => value.replace('home.mytest1.', ''));

console.log(alteredNameList);
```

Or you can use a regular expression, if the thing you want to replace changes slightly:

```js
const nameList = [
  'home.mytest1.James Thomas 14-47',
  'home.mytest2.George Simon 7-2',
  'home.mytest3.Sandy Kylie 3-15'
];

const alteredNameList = nameList.map(value => value.replace(/^home\.mytest\d+\./, ''));

console.log(alteredNameList);
```

The benefit of an expression is that you can determine if the portion you want to replace appears at the beginning, the end, or anywhere in-between.